# Action not defined laravel/php controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, action

I am having a problem with a controller action in a laravel project and I have no idea why, since everything seems fine.

Heres my route concerning the error part:

```
Route::get('/reminds','RemindController@index');
Route::get('/reminds','RemindController@create');
```

Heres the create and index method that are defined in the RemindController.php file:

```
    public function index()
{
    $reminds  = Remind::all();
    return View::make('remind.index', compact('reminds'));
}



public function create()
{
    try {


        $listyears = RemindController::generate_list(date('Y')-100, 101);
        $listmonths = RemindController::generate_list(1, 12);
        $listdays = RemindController::generate_list(1, 31);

        return View::make('remind.create', compact('listyears', 'listmonths', 'listdays'));
    } catch (Exception $e){
        App:abort(404);
    }
}
```

In create.blade.php(of remind view) I have this that calls the problematic index:

```
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h2>create reminder</h2>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    {!! Form::open(['action'=> 'RemindController@index', 'class' => 'form']) !!}
```

The problem is that each time I try to access the page that calls the reminder creation form I get error:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Action App\Http\Controllers\RemindController@index not defined. (View: C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\project\prototype\resources\views\remind\create.blade.php)
```

However I clearly defined it. I dont understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route::get('/reminds','RemindController@index');
Route::get('/reminds','RemindController@create');

this is the same route, so technically on this part you have an issue already. try to change the HTTP protocol or rename your route instead.

```
Route::get('reminds','RemindController@index');
Route::post('reminds','RemindController@create');
```

or

```
Route::get('reminds','RemindController@index');
Route::get('reminds/create','RemindController@create');
```

also omit the first slash on your route already, there's no use of doing that.

--- update*

instead of using the static call Route

you may use something like this

```
$router->group(function(){
   $this->get('/',['as' => "homepage" , 'use' => "MainController@homepage"] );

   $this->group(['prefix' => "dashboard",'as' => "dashboard"],function(){
      $this->get('/',['as' => "index",'use' => "DashboardController@index"]);
});
});
```

Comment: thank you! well explained. is this way to do new since laravel 5?

Comment: no actually . static call on the global variable are no longer recommended. you can use the route()->, session()-> , cache()-> etc rather than calling it by Route::() , Session:: , Cache::  etc, i'll update my answer to make this clearer

Answer (score 1):

You defined two routes with same url and same method

```
Route::get('/reminds','RemindController@index');
Route::get('/reminds','RemindController@create');
```

Rename one of them

```
Route::get('/reminds','RemindController@index');
Route::get('/reminds/create','RemindController@create');
```

Comment: Route::get('/reminds/create','RemindController@create'); should probably be Route::post('/reminds','RemindController@create');

Comment: @jcorry his create method is just there to display data, so get it's ok imo. post is more for the store method

Answer (score 0):

You have written same route url for same http verb.

Just rename them as your requirement.
A suggestion to add name() for route for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone, I had this same error, but my issue was I had accidentally used `Route::resource()` when defining my route instead of `Route::get()`. I assume this would be the same scenario for `Route::post()`.